# How to achieve this table style?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have the following element in my InDesign page, which currently is done by manually placing 9 rectangles, and a line object together:

[image]

How could I replicate this, with a pure table object in InDesign? I want to use tables, because if later on, I want to change the color of these tables, which will appear multiply times in the documents, I would want to be able to quickly do it, with modifying a table or cell style for example.

I've managed to clear the outer border of the table, and all the inner borders also, but I can't find a way, to separate them from each other.

Comment: If you only need the color to be dynamic, you could simple change the swatch later on. Or you could use object styles. It doesn't *have* to be a table to be dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlight the table and choose **`Table > Cell Options > Strokes & Fills`** from the menu.

<sub>(Preview [unselected] table on right, highlighted [selected] table on left)</sub>

[image]

Merely add a white stroke to the cells and a background color.

<sub>CS6 screenshot, but it's basically the same options in newer versions.</sub>

Comment: I first thought about answering this, but then noticed the red boxes (cells) kind of have their own black outline in that very small image in the question, so not sure if just adding strokes can be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that can be easily done using tables. You need to add very narrow in-between rows and columns to introduce that spacing between the cells. You can control how high a row can be and how wide a column can be, and using small values you can simulate this kind of spacing.

Later edit:

- if you need clean red cells with white in between, look at Scott's answer
- if you need the red cells to have an inside black outline, and then also white in between them, you need to combine both answers into a solution